# Why does my sliding miter saw go slanted down the line instead of straight?

Tags: miter-saw

I have a Chicago Electric 12” compound sliding miter saw, model 98194. Instead of sliding straight, it slants.

It veers by about 1/16” going from back to front. It cuts slanted.

The fence is square with the blade. The miter angle is 0 degrees, as is the bevel.

The blade is new, a 12” Diablo. I’ve tightened it. It is not loose.

Here are images showing the blade in its pushed back position and its pulled-forward position: https://imgur.com/a/37mupFK

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you verify zero really zero?

Comment: Yes, both the miter gauge and bevel. Also, when I set the bevel to 45 and slide the saw, I notice it veers into the angled side of the kerf line space or whatever it’s called.

Comment: I’m confused: if you cut a wide piece, is the cut 90° or something else? Is the cut straight?

Comment: One detail not given *might* be relevant and that's to do with how old the saw is. If it's basically brand new some buildup of gunk seems unlikely, but if you've used it a bit then that's maybe a possibility (we had a vaguely similar situation in a previous Q&A, and there was sawdust buildup inside). If you do go the returns route it is extremely straightforward at HF, they're brilliant for that. If you have never seen a video about it there are a few on YT, although I know it's not in my view history I can probably hunt down the most recent one I watched for you if you'd like.

Comment: Chicago Electric.

Comment: @gnicko, that might be just a tad too cryptic for the OP (or anyone else not familiar with HF's house-brand hierarchy).

Comment: It's also covered fairly well (I believe) in my answer - "you get what you pay for"...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the gap to one edge of the kerf plate is larger when the blade is slid all the way forward than it is when it's slid all the way back. If that's a correct understanding, then I'd say that the slides on the saw aren't perpendicular to the fence or that the motor is, somehow, not mounted square on the carriage. Generally, this doesn't seem to be a setting that's fixable. I would be curious to know if the blade is still at 90° to the fence when it's slid all the way toward you (use a larger square to test this).

I would suggest that this is a manufacturing defect and that, unfortunately, you've gotten what you paid for<sup>*</sup>. If it's still within 90 days of purchase, take it back to Harbor Freight, explain the issue, and it's *very* likely they'll go get a replacement from stock and give you a new one. If it's beyond 90 days, the warranty is up, and you may as well fiddle with it to see if you can get the slide mechanism adjusted.

No, I don't have a clue how you'd do that. I've not had to do that with either of the DeWalt miter saws I own, nor with my FIL's Rigid miter saw. At this point, though, the saw is, essentially, useless for making accurate cross-cuts (it's sole purpose in life), so starting the disassembly process isn't going to leave it any more broken than it already is.

---

<sup>*</sup>This isn't a slam on Harbor Freight in general. I'm a big fan of theirs and have had great success with many of their products. I don't, though, buy power tools from them unless it's for a very specific purpose. If I do and the tool lasts through the project I bought it for, I'm very happy. If it lasts *longer* than that, I'm ecstatic! It's a matter of realizing what you're buying and being willing to take the associated risks.

I have had a couple of their hand tools fail on me. I had absolutely zero questions when I returned them - they directed me to pick up a new one off the shelf, they scanned some barcodes, punched buttons on their register, gave me a new receipt and told me to have a good day. I'd imagine the return process on the saw will be similar if it's within the warranty period.

Comment: I won't even go into Harbor Freight any more...  I won't buy Black and Decker anymore either...

Comment: I love HF _for some things_. TBF, I just bought their 2HP dust collector. If you look at YT, there are a lot of reviews raving about it, and also showing hundreds of mods to make it even more effective (any DC that doesn't have a separator can be improved by adding one, any DC that uses a bag as a filter can get significant improvement by adding a filter, etc.) I'm just very aware of what I'm buying and keep my expectations appropriate.

Comment: @bowlturner, I understand the reluctance, but as I learned from some recent YT vids HF has made strides to improve over recent years and *are* worth another look. Totally agree about B&D unfortunately! Hard for me since I used to be a B&D fanboy :-( but the cheapening of the Workmate was the most visible indicator of a slow slide into mediocrity (and beyond). I actually have 3 vintage B&D drills in the house currently, incl. one nearly my age and still going strong! Both it and another required the chuck be de-rusted, cleaned and lubed but other than that the drill were in fine working order.

Comment: @Graphus, that's good to hear, but forgive me if I wait a little longer, since there are plenty of other places to get good quality tools yet.

Comment: @bowlturner, obviously true, but the thing is, at the same price point? To illustrate the point that cheap does not *equal* bad/shoddy, over here in Europe we have access to a couple of budget tool ranges through German-based supermarkets Aldi and Lidl, and there are innumerable testimonials — including from me :-) —  about how they can punch above their weight. And to give a specific example from HF, their wonderful little 1x30 belt sander has many happy owners going back years, and has even gotten decent reviews from full-time pros such as Walter Sorrels (a knifemaker).

Comment: I’ve also heard anecdotes about how HF miraculously produced a decent tool. That wouldn’t induce me to go buy one, though. I’d agree with the ‘I need this particular tool for exactly one job and the economics for that make sense’ stance.

Comment: As we dive further off topic, I've started to believe that HF is now producing far better quality tools than they used to. Their Icon line of mechanics tools/boxes have been compared _very_ favorably to the tool-truck brands (Snap-On, Mac, etc.) by professional mechanics. I've seen one guy _standing_ on a drawer from their new line of tool boxes. However, old prejudices die hard and I'm still troubled by spending a lot of $$ on powered tools from them. In particular, their Bauer & Hercules line of cordless tools seem to be pretty decent, but I've already got 4 different battery platforms...